# Which script contains scroll to top? Inspect network elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am working with the following theme:

http://dtspalab.wpengine.com/

The theme has a scroll to top functionality and I would like to locate which javascript contains the scroll to top code.

When I inspect the scroll to top button, then click the network tab, I am unable to locate which script contains the scroll to top code.

Could someone help walk me through how to determine and locate the specific script I am seeking? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why would you click the network tab? Click on 'Event Listeners' on the right-hand side and it will show you the `scroll` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, if you check the `Event Listeners` dev tool and take a look at the `click` events, you'll see `a:toTop` has a click event listener in the following script: http://dtspalab.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/spalab/framework/js/public/jquery.ui.totop.min.js?ver=4.8.2

Can be seen in the following screenshot

[image: Event Listeners]

Comment: Should mention that this is in Chrome. The equivalent section in Safari doesn't reveal the file where the event listener is attached.

Comment: Thanks, updated this answer to start with saying this is in Chrome Dev tools

Comment: It is coming from this file: "http://dtspalab.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/spalab/framework/js/public/jquery.ui.totop.min.js". This plugin crating element to click automatically by this line: "$('body').append('<a href="#" id="' + settings.containerID + '">' + settings.text + '</a>');"

Comment: Thank you snapjs! I found the Firefox "ev" label. Thank you kindly, excellent! Appreciate this knowledge very much!